# h-Cobordism Theorem and Dynamical Systems

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, reference-request

Does anyone know anything about applications of the h-cobordism theorem to dynamical systems?

Comment: via Morse theory, there's a really well-known application you might say going the other way, see e.g.: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Morse-Smale_systems#Morse-Smale_Gradient_Fields_and_Relations_to_Topology and cited references

Comment: For me, as a not-at-all expert on this, it would be nice if the question was more detailed. While of course I still could not give an answer, I  might learn something from reading it.  

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at John Franks's 1982 CBMS monograph (#49) *Homology and Dynamical Systems*. The $h$-cobordism theorem appears on page 13. It is used in connection with gradient-like flows on manifolds of dimension greater than 5.